# debugging apollo, docker and typescript on VS code

Tags: node.js, apollo, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make the debugger work on VS code using node but without any success as breakpoints are not hitting.
I tried to set the launch.json in many different configs but with no luck.

```
"type": "node",
"request": "attach",
"name": "Attach",
"port": 9229,
"skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**"
]
},

{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Server",
    "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/index.ts",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

I am using a graphql running on node apollo and typescript on my machine with Visual Studio Code